# Как конвертировать dat формат в csv?

Tags: python, csv

Мне необходимо конвертировать dat формат в csv. Необходимый результат должен быть таким:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вместо это в результате получается это: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
import time
import binascii
import csv
#import serial
#import numpy as np

with open('file_2019_11_01_n00130.dat', 'rb') as input_file:
    lines = input_file.readlines()
    newLines = []
    for line in lines:
        newLine = line.strip(b'|').split()
        newLines.append(newLine)

with open('file.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    file_writer = csv.writer(output_file)
    file_writer.writerows(newLines)
```

Comment: Чтото неправильно с кодировкой, перепроверь, 99% уверен что кодировка. Кодировка дат файла и кодировка питон скрипта должна совпадать и при открытии csv указать правильную кодировку надо.

Comment: что такое DAT файл? Это бинарный формат?